# xsl count node with attributes

Tags: xslt

I've the below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter num="A">
    <title>
        <content-style font-style="bold">PART 1 GENERAL PRINCIPLES</content-style>
    </title>
    <section level="sect1">
        <title>
            <content-style font-style="bold">Chapter 1: THE NEW ARBITRATION ORDINANCE</content-style>
        </title>
        <section level="sect2">
            <title>INTRODUCTION</title>
        </section>
        <section level="sect2" num="1.">
            <title>INTRODUCTION</title>
        </section>
        <section level="sect2"  num="2.">
            <title>INTRODUCTION 1</title>
        </section>
        <section level="sect2"  num="3.">
            <title>INTRODUCTION 2</title>
        </section>
    </section>
</chapter>
```

and when I use the below xslt

```
<xsl:number count="section"/>
```

the number is starting from 2, but I want from 1 as, the first sec2 doesn't have a num attribute, please let me know how can I do this, also I need to use only number count function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are asking for the count of all section nodes:

```
<xsl:number count="section"/>
```

Try changing your `count` xpath string to specify only those nodes with a `num` attribute:

```
<xsl:number count="section[@num]"/>
```